# why My UserSession in mvc controller is Null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, servicestack

I have ServiceStack in my mvc project and I'm trying to share a session between ServiceStack and ASP MVC .. I follow all the steps from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions to share a session, but when I try to get the values of UserSession in my asp mvc controller it displays a NULL VAUE...why is Null? I have this code

AppHost.cs

```
{
    ControllerBase<CustomUserSession>

    public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
    {
        public string CustomProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string CustomProperty2 { get; set; }

    }

    public class AppHost
        : AppHostBase
    {       
        public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
            : base("StarterTemplate ASP.NET Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

            //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

            //Configure User Defined REST Paths
            Routes
              .Add<Hello>("/hello")
              .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name*}");

            //Uncomment to change the default ServiceStack configuration
            //SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
            //});

            //Enable Authentication
            //ConfigureAuth(container);

            //Register all your dependencies
            container.Register(new TodoRepository());           

            //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
            ServiceStackController.CatchAllController = reqCtx => container.TryResolve<HomeController>();
        }

        /* Uncomment to enable ServiceStack Authentication and CustomUserSession
        private void ConfigureAuth(Funq.Container container)
        {
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();

            //Default route: /auth/{provider}
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                    new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                    new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                    new BasicAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                })); 

            //Default route: /register
            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature()); 

            //Requires ConnectionString configured in Web.Config
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
                new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

            var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
            authRepo.CreateMissingTables();
        }
        */

        public static void Start()
        {
            new AppHost().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController.com

```
 public class HomeController : ControllerBase
        {
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Sharing Sessions Btw SS and ASP MVC";

                return View();
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Login()
            {

                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Login(User request)
            {
                var user_Session = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<CustomUserSession>(CacheClient);
                return Json(user_Session);
            }
```

So the user_Session is null ... can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting from [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs), e.g:

```
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User request)
    {
        CustomUserSession userSession = base.UserSession;
        return Json(userSession);
    }
}
```

Also if you want to use a Custom UserSession (i.e. other than the AuthUserSession default) you need to tell ServiceStack how to create it, by specifying it in the AuthFeature constructor:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings), 
    }));
```

Comment: Hi, I tryed and still I get null values @mythz

Comment: @rr7 Works fine for me. Make sure you've read and followed the [MVC + ServiceStack integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) guide.

Comment: Already check https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration follow every step and still get null values. @mythz

Comment: @rr7 I've added a note about how to tell ServiceStack you're using a CustomUserSession.

Comment: @rr7 it's in the commented code in your section, i.e. `var appSettings = new AppSettings()`, which just looks in your web.config's `<appSettings/>`. You can also use `var appSettings = new DictionarySettings()` which just looks in the string dictionary for settings instead.

Comment: samething... null value in CustomProperty. Why the Session is not created? I just follow your coments here's some images of AppHost.cs [link](http://s12.postimg.org/xnxeme17x/App_Host.png) and HomeController.cs [link](http://s14.postimg.org/6ngt8361d/Home_Controller.png) @mythz

Comment: @rr7 It shouldn't be null, maybe the session hasn't been created yet. It's initialized in the [SessionFeature's Global RequestFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/SessionFeature.cs#L33), which gets run when you touch a ServiceStack service. To force creating the session in MVC you can try calling ` SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession` again, with the `AuthFeature` configuration enabled. Other than that, I'm out of ideas - you may need to debug it to see what's going on, src is included in NuGet packages, [see debug instructions](http://bit.ly/HkzWLe).